# In Firestore rules how do you check the id of the requesting document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I mean I want to check to be sure the document id of the request is the same as the document id in the database.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.resource.id == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Also tried this and it also didn't work:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.resource.id == resource.id;
    }
  }
}
```

I've searched online for hours and every single post is about using authentication uid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want to make sure the uid in request matches name of the user document, then use this:

```
 match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
```

and if you want to allow new users to be created add this too:

```
     allow create: if request.auth != null;
```

more details : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

Comment: Hi doesn't `request.auth.uid` have to do with authentication? I'm not using authentication.

Comment: He is ,  otherwise  he didn't have  match /users/{userId}

Comment: I'm the OP :). What I'm saying is that I'm setting a hardware ID called `ANDROID_ID` as the ID of each document. I want to check if the document ID in the database is equal to the request's document ID.

Comment: sorry :) 
yes request.auth.ui is based on firebase authentication.
but then why are adding match /users/{userId}

Comment: So what's the way to get the id of the document in the database?

Comment: If I have a collection called `users` then what should I write other than `/users/{userId}`?

Comment: firebase rules are based on document id. so the document id of the request is already used to find the matching rule.   if you want to doubly check  then store the id inside the request payload as well then use request.resource.data.id  == userId

Comment: This never even occurred to me. Why was I looing for a way to verify if the user had the ID when Firestore searches documents by their ID? I thought I was much smarter than this :(

Comment: I think what I really want is a way to prevent someone from reading other documents. Meaning if they just made a request to my database to read all documents in a collection the request would be denied. So what I need is a rule that says the user's request must contain an ID or else it would be rejected.

Comment: However in order to save data, is there a way to get the ID of a document in the security rules? I'm using the free version of firestore so I don't want to add an extra field so I can write `request.resource.data.id == userId`

Comment: A "read" rule can be broken into "get" and "list",
you can allow get (so anyone with a valid id can read that document) and prevent "list" so people can not get a full list of your collection
in other word only "allow get"